# wordpress custom add_rewrite_rule not working on pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I have the following function in my functions.php file. What it does is that it allows me to use 2 custom taxonomies together.

```
function nfh_custom_rewrite_rules() {
   add_rewrite_rule('^product_cat/(.*)/bins/(.*)?', 'index.php?product_cat=$matches[1]&bins=$matches[2]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'nfh_custom_rewrite_rules');
```

so I can have a URL like this:

```
mysite.com/product_cat/homeware/bins/promo/
```

.. and this works fine

The problem I'm having is that pagination doesnt seem to be working. as soon as I go to page 2:

```
mysite.com/product_cat/homeware/bins/promo/page/2/
```

it just throws a not found error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: do you need to make it using a code or plugin is preferable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested but check as below. This may help.

```
function nfh_custom_rewrite_rules() {
   add_rewrite_rule('^product_cat/(.*)/bins/(.*)/page/([0-9]{1,})/?', 'index.php?product_cat=$matches[1]&bins=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[3]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'nfh_custom_rewrite_rules');
```

Comment: Glad to help..:)